# Extract data from string to be stored into variables

Tags: php, search, preg-match

I need to find the Author, Date and Body of each string (see example below) and store them each into a variable. I know it'll involve regex but I am not good enough to figure out how to account for strings that may include commas and other non alpha characters.

Example string:

> {Author=user1020, Date=1/7/2017, Body=I've had the booda dome (the
>   same one!) for ten years and it's still going strong. Nothing crazy or
>   fancy but I think they appreciate the bit of privacy .}

And store it in variables like below:

```
$author = "user1020";
$date = "1/7/2017";
$body = "I've had the booda dome (the same one!) for ten years and it's still going strong. Nothing crazy or fancy but I think they appreciate the bit of privacy .";
```

Comment: Is that the exact string pattern? Where are you getting it from? It looks like it could be json except for missing the quotes.

Comment: If it's just a string then and you can use "explode" PHP function but make sure the format must be same. ex. explode(',' , $string);.

Comment: ^ I second this, if you know what you're looking for just do a check on each explode position

Comment: I am worried because of the body part might include a comma. It looks like json but it is not.

Comment: Sorry, does not need to use regex, but just need a way to extract the author, date and body from the string, thanks.

Comment: Try using this: `(Author|Date|Body)=(.*?)(?:,|})`. [Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MHx2ZB/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's not miss a good chance to teach some excellent one-liners!!!

Input:

```
$in = "{Author=user1020, Date=1/7/2017, Body=I've had the booda dome (the same one!) for ten years and it's still going strong. Nothing crazy or fancy but I think they appreciate the bit of privacy .}";
```

Method:

```
[$author, $date, $body] = preg_split('/(^|,)[^=]+?=/', substr($in, 0, -1), 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Output:

```
echo "$author<br>$date<br>$body";
/*
user1020
1/7/2017
I've had the booda dome (the same one!) for ten years and it's still going strong. Nothing crazy or fancy but I think they appreciate the bit of privacy .
*/
```

My regex pattern explodes the string between each desired substring and returns them in order, without capture groups or an array that includes "fullstring matches" like `preg_match()`.  I did have to tear off the trailing `}` manually before splitting.  And, of course, destructuring array syntax (or use `list()`) creates the desired variables.

---

p.s. If anyone is concerned about accuracy (or if one of the targeted substrings has a symbol in it that may monkeywrench my splitting pattern) this more literal alternative will provide the same output (and takes care of the trailing `}`):

```
[$author, $date, $body] = preg_split('/\{Author=|, Date=|, Body=|\}/', $in, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

---

And for anyone who doesn't want to leave the comfort of `preg_match()` with capture groups...

```
[, $author, $date, $body] = preg_match('/Author=([^,]*), Date=([^,]*), Body=([^}]*)/', $in, $out) ? $out : ['', '', '', ''];
```

Explanation:  preg_match returns `1`, `0`, or `false`, so it is used as an inline conditional where the fullstring and capture data is passed on `1` and empty values are passed on `0` or `false`.  The destructuring array has an empty first element because we don't need to assign a variable to the fullstring match value.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a better way and there are no checks for different situations but an idea to get it working :

```
$mString = "{Author=user1020, Date=1/7/2017, Body=I've had the booda dome (the same one!) for ten years and it's still going strong. Nothing crazy or fancy but I think they appreciate the bit of privacy .}";


$mString = returnToArray($mString);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($mString);
echo "</pre>";

function returnToArray($mString){

    $mFinalArray = null;

    $mString = str_replace('{','',$mString);
    $mString = str_replace('}','',$mString);

    $mString = explode(',', $mString);

    foreach($mString as $string){

        if(strpos(strtolower($string), 'author') !== false){ // If you find author in string 
            $mFinalArray['author'] = explode('=',$string)[1]; // Explode at '=' and take the "right" part (in fact it becomes an array and [1] is the right part of string in the specific example
        }
        else if(strpos(strtolower($string), 'date') !== false){ // If you find date in string 
            $mFinalArray['date'] = explode('=',$string)[1];
        }
        else if(strpos(strtolower($string), 'body') !== false){  // If you find body in string 
            $mFinalArray['body'] = explode('=',$string)[1];
        }

    }

    return $mFinalArray;

}
```

> Output :

```
Array
(
    [author] => user1020
    [date] => 1/7/2017
    [body] => I've had the booda dome (the same one!) for ten years and it's still going strong. Nothing crazy or fancy but I think they appreciate the bit of privacy .}
)
```

As for the "checking"...for example, if you change the `$mString` body part and add "author" to that string, the above won't work. An idea would be to change all `ifs` and add at the end a `=` , like`'author='` so there will be always `=` but not quite what we want.

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY want to use regex and that you are REALLY sure that your string will have this exact shape, for the author you can do :

```
/Author=(\w+),/g
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/njvDjF/3)

For the date :

```
/Date=(.+),/g
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/njvDjF/4)

For the body :

```
/Body=(.+)}/g
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/njvDjF/1)

Answer (score 1):

Regex solution with PHP

```
<?php

$string = "{Author=user1020, Date=1/7/2017, Body=I've had the booda dome (the same one!) for ten years and it's still going strong. Nothing crazy or fancy but I think they appreciate the bit of privacy .}";
$info = Array();

if (preg_match('/{Author=(?<author>.*), Date=/', $string, $matches)) {
    $info += $matches;
}

if (preg_match('/Date=(?<date>.*), Body=/', $string, $matches)) {
    $info += $matches;
}

if (preg_match('/Body=(?<body>.*)}/', $string, $matches)) {
    $info += $matches;
}

// to see output
// print_r($info)

$author = $info['author'];
$date = $info['date'];
$body = $info['body'];

?>
```